# Resizing table cells dynamically in iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to make a Twitter client with `XCode 4.2`. (`iOS version 5`.) I want my application's main timeline to look similar to the Twitter iOS app's timeline:

[image: Twitter's UI]

I am using a `UITableView` with a prototype cell containing a label and three buttons. Below is the code I'm using to set the height:

```
            - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"TweetContainerCell";
                UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
                @try {
                    UILabel* tweetLabel;
                    if(cell != nil) {
                        tweetLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
                        NSString* tweetText = tweetLabel.text;
                        CGSize expectedLabelSize = [tweetText sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:tweetLabel.font.fontName size:20] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(CGFLOAT_MIN, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                        //[tweetLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(tweetLabel.frame.origin.x, tweetLabel.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, expectedLabelSize.height)];
                        //[cell.textLabel setFrame:tweetLabel.bounds];
                        //[tweetLabel sizeToFit];
                        //[cell setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.y, cell.frame.size.width, expectedLabelSize.height)];
                        //[cell sizeToFit];
                        NSLog(@"Font size: %f", expectedLabelSize.height);
                        return (expectedLabelSize.height * 2);
                    }
                }
                /* Imgur URL: http://i.imgur.com/lHnsAsP.png */
                /* http://i.imgur.com/hA9EKfI.png */
                @catch (NSException* exception) {
                    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
                }
                return 0;
            }
```

However, this is what my app ends up looking like:

[image: My application]

The problems are:

1) Each cell seems to have the same height as the tallest cell in the whole table, instead of having different heights.

2) Because of this, the space between the cell's top border and the text is different for each cell (because `iOS` centers the text vertically).

I am learning `iOS` development and being unable to do such a simple thing, even after doing a lot of research and spending a lot of hours, seems really discouraging. Any help is greatly appreciated.

(In case the information I have given is not enough, here's the ZIP file containing the whole project: https://db.tt/m5suxWCj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your label has not been created, since `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is initially called before `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which is where your cell is created. In `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` you should determine the height of the cell as efficiently as possible, without involving UIViews.

To achieve this, you should store the `NSString` elsewhere in your table view data source, and calculate `expectedLabelSize` based on that.

Note also that `sizeWithFont:` is deprecated in IOS 7, so for IOS 7 and beyond you should use `sizeWithAttributes:` instead.